# Caliburn.Micro new window does not follow conventions

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have my app up and running with CM. The shell view contains multiple ContentControls which itself contain views. Those are assigned by convention as they got a name matching a property in the view model.

I got a WPF window (at least its class inherits from `Window`) which is opened from my app with `windowManager.ShowDialog(viewModel)`. Inside this window again I have ContentControls but those do not bind to view model properties.

I already tried to set `cal:View.ApplyConventions="True"` on the window but that did not help either. I also used `ViewModelBinder.Bind(viewmodel, view, null)` to *bind* vm and view before showing the window - does not work either.

How can I make sure my opened window (modal dialog) makes use of the same CM enhancements?

This is the view:

```
<Window x:Class="Client.Views.History.HistoryView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
    Title="Historie" Height="300" Width="300"
                   cal:View.ApplyConventions="True"
    >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="64" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="RecordView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="DarkKhaki" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DarkSeaGreen"  />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The border is displayed so the view is loaded. The DataContext should be set by caliburn micro. This is the view model:

```
public class HistoryViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{

    #region Fields --------------------------------------------------------

    private readonly HeaderViewModel headerView;
    private readonly RecordViewModel recordView;

    #endregion

    public HistoryViewModel()
    {
        this.headerView = IoC.Get<HeaderViewModel>();
        this.recordView = IoC.Get<RecordViewModel>();
    }

    public HeaderViewModel HeaderView
    {
        get { return this.headerView; }
    }

    public RecordViewModel RecordView
    {
        get { return this.recordView; }
    }
}
```

The constructor runs, the view models are created (not null). But the properties `HeaderView` and `RecordView` are never accessed.

To launch this I use this code:

```
HistoryViewModel viewModel = IoC.Get<HistoryViewModel>();
windowManager.ShowDialog(viewModel);
```

---

It works when binding the model explicitly like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="HeaderView" cal:View.Model="{Binding HeaderView}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<ContentControl x:Name="RecordView" cal:View.Model="{Binding RecordView}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
```

But I would like to know how the *standard mechaniscs* can be re-enabled.

Comment: It might help to see some code. Is the `DataContext` correct on the window itself, and does the intended view at least display correctly?

Comment: @Chris I added some of the code. Yes the view for the window is displayed - just the contents for its ContentControls not.

Answer (score 1):

I think your HistoryViewModel needs to be a Conductor to get this to work.  Since you want both child VMs to show at the same time, you would inherit from Conductor.Collection.AllActive.

John

Comment: If that is the case, why do I not have to do that for `ShellViewModel` (meaning the main view when the app starts)?

Comment: What does your `ShellViewModel` inherit from? =o

Comment: @ZoolWay: because the ShellViewModel is invoked directly by the Bootstrapper and it treats any VM it opens as if it were a Conductor.  Please refer to http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition for a description of this behavior.